# How to parse data in RPG

Tags: db2-400, rpgle

I have an order number which is character 10 positions.

I would like to know where the leading blanks end. Only blanks.
So if the number is

'    012345'  I want 012345 - Can I do this in RPG? I have tried some FREE codes
but have trouble getting to work in general. So I prefer the old way
or Free is ok  if we must.

So what i need to know is, how many positions of the 10 position field are having data? so if the data is 012345 this means 6 positions are filled and 4 are blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%scan` to locate the blank.

```
dcl-s source char(10) inz('12345');
dcl-s pos zoned(5);

pos = %scan(' ':source) - 1;
*inlr = *on;
```

After the eval pos = 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deal with the value without leading blanks, you can use `%trim` or `%trimL`.  The former will trim spaces from the front and end.  The latter will only trim spaces from the front (left).

```
newOrder = %trimL( originalOrder );
```

Although your example is a bit odd.  Either you typo'd what you want (two 3's?) or if you really do want to insert a 3, then that would require more work.  Let me know.

**Edit:**  Maybe this logic better answers what you're looking to do.

To count the number of non-blanks, you can do this:

```
valueCount = %len( %trim( originalOrder ) );
```

And if you need to know the number of blanks instead, it's simply:

```
blankCount = %len( originalOrder ) - %len( %trim( originalOrder ) );
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: typo thanks. what I want to know is, how to determine how many of the 10 positions have a number in them. So that if the value is 012345 - that mean 6. How can I code this to know that we have 6 as the actual data and 4 leading blanks.

Comment: I updated my answer.  Hope that helps.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XLATE to replace all blanks in your string with zeros